# python program to print the smallest number possible ex: input 23780 output: 20378

Tags: python

```
def large(n):
    s=0
    for i in range(1,10):
        copy=n
        while copy>0:
            r=copy%10
            if (r==i):
                s=(s*10)+r
            if (r==0) and (s>0) and (s<10):
                s=(s*10)+r
            copy=copy//10
    print(s)
    

n=int(input("enter: "))
large(n)
```

I wrote this but its not working if any of the numbers are being repeated

Comment: Wouldnt the smallest number in your example be 02378? or always `int("".join(sorted(n)))`?

Comment: yes but thats the problem the 0's (if any) have to come after the first number.

Comment: what are the rules that define smallest number.  please explain the problem in more detail.  explain how its "not working"

Comment: python function to print the smallest number possible for example 1720202 it has to print 1002227 and not 12227 the number of digits has to be same. in my program if any of the numbers are repeated then its not giving the right output and you cannot use list.

Answer (score 0):

First we will sort the digits, after that we want to swap the first digit that is not `0` with a zero, we are sure that after sorting if there are any zero then in the sorted string the first digit will be `0` and the first digit that is not `0` is after all `0`s in the number. If there are no `0`s, then the code will "swap" the element at position 0 with itself, so it will also work.

```
def large(n):
    sn = sorted(str(n))
    zeros = sn.count('0')
    ln = list(sn)
    ln[zeros], ln[0] = ln[0], ln[zeros]
    return ''.join(ln)


n = int(input("enter: "))
print(large(n))
```